# A counter that behaves in two ways in a tabular environment

Tags: tables, counters

I was testing code just for fun and found a strange behavior (for me) of a counter in the "tabular" environment:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\begin{document}
    \def\yy{&}
    \newcounter{numk}
    \begin{tabular}{ll}\hline
    numk \yy actual numk\\\hline
    \setcounter{numk}{1}
    \whiledo{\value{numk}<5}{
    \thenumk 
     \yy
     \multiply\value{numk} by 3\relax\; \; \thenumk \\%
     \ifnum\value{numk}=4\hline\end{tabular}\fi
     \stepcounter{numk}
      }
\end{document}
```

The result is  [image]

But, I wonder... why was the counter "numk" modified, in the second column, and why does it return to its natural state in the first column? That is, if "numk =3", then the following, after `\stepcounter{numk}` should be "4", but not.

But if I change the code, then the counter "numk"  it changes as "expected"

```
\newcounter{numk}
\setcounter{numk}{1}
\whiledo{\value{numk}<5}{
   \thenumk 
   \;**\;
   \multiply\value{numk} by 3\relax\;  \thenumk\\
 \stepcounter{numk}
   }
```

And I get [image]

So what happens in "tabular" with the counter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the `\multiply` is made `\global`, it acts in the expected way.  I would therefore guess that while `\setcounter` is automatically `\global`, `\multiply` is not.  And if not global, then the effect of the `\multiply` is lost at the end of the `tabular` cell, which is its own group.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\begin{document}
    \def\yy{&}
    \newcounter{numk}
    \begin{tabular}{ll}\hline
    numk \yy actual numk\\\hline
    \setcounter{numk}{1}
    \whiledo{\value{numk}<120}{
    \thenumk 
     \yy
     \global\multiply\value{numk} by 3\relax\; \; \thenumk \\%
     \stepcounter{numk}
      }
     \end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]